# Changing the visibility of a textview in a listview

Tags: android, listview, onclick, visibility

I have a listview which is build up of two textviews coming from a separate layout file. I use a `BaseAdapter` to build the list from a JSON file.

I would like the first textview (Caption) to be clickable, if clicked that it shows the second textview (Text), and if clicked again that it  hides it.

When I use an `onClick` (`android:onClick="ClText"`) I get an error. I think I should use something of an `onClickListener`, but since I'm new to Android I'm not quite sure how to use it.

Can someone help me out with the code please?

Comment: just use onClickListener in code, because the onclick attribute cause many problems

Comment: Ok, but then how do I identify the right view? Since all views in the ListView have the same ID (mTxtvCaption and mTxtvText) I need it to identify the right mTxtvCaption that has been clicked and to make the right mTxtvText visible

Comment: @Tino, you need to make sure to give your text views unique IDs.

Comment: i know, but since its a listview, the textviews are duplicated multiple times...

Comment: @Tino, this distinction between the TextViews is made for each parent view in the list when it is created in the getView method in your adapter. You have to handle the onClick of your caption TextView there. See my answer for a code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the onClickListener for the first item in the getView method of your adapter class that extends BaseAdapter. Here's an example to illustrate what you're trying to do.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private ArrayList<Thing> mThingArray;

    public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<Thing> thingArray) {
        mThingArray = thingArray;
    }

    // Get the data item associated with the specified position in the data set.
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return thingArray.get(position);
    }

    // Get a View that displays the data at the specified position in the data set.
    // You can either create a View manually or inflate it from an XML layout file.
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null){
            // LayoutInflater class is used to instantiate layout XML file into its corresponding View objects.
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.one_of_list, null);
        }

        TextView captionTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.caption);
        TextView txt2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

        captionTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           if(txt2.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE){
           txt2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
           txt2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
       }
    });

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to use a click listener with java:

```
TextView txt = (TextView )findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
TextView txt2 = (TextView )findViewById(R.id.TextView2);
txt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        txt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txt2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

Honestly though, instead of changing the visibility of different textViews, why don't you just alter the TextView text?  It would be much simpler and wouldn't require multiple TextViews.

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting there :) I have to use multiple textviews, since the JSON contains a lot of titles matched to text. At startup the app needs to only show the titles, and onclick the matching text has to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to switch between two textview , you can simply use a ViewSwitcher. it allow you to switch between the view that are into it. You just have to call the nextView() method and this method is cycling, so you can call nextView() endlessly

You will be able to change the view that is display.

Then you can add the same onClickListener to these to textview write something like this :

```
TextView txt = (TextView )findViewById(R.id.TextView1);

txt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
      viewSwitcher.nextView();
}
});
```