# Changong the visibilty/invisibiloty of a TextView Using onClick Method

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-activity

I am trying to make two textviews appear and disappear on the same click and then on the next click vica versa appear and disappear. I have read some posts on this site, [Make Textview Visible by Pressing a Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203208/make-textview-visible-by-pressing-a-button) and [Changing the visibility of a textview in a listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769890/changing-the-visibility-of-a-textview-in-a-listview), but the solutions in these examples does not work for me. However, I have borrowed some of their ideas.

```
   package com.mycompany.screenchangeapplication;

    import android.app.*;
    import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
    import android.os.*;
    import android.view.*;
    import android.widget.*;

public class ScreenActivity extends Activity {

    public RelativeLayout container;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen);

        container = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.ScreenActivity);
        container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                changeScreen(v);
            }
        });
    }

    public void changeScreen(View v) {
        ColorDrawable cd = (ColorDrawable) this.container.getBackground();
        TextView ON = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ON);
        TextView OFF = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.OFF);

        if (cd != null && cd.getColor() == getResources().getColor(R.color.WHITE)) {
            container.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.BLACK));
            OFF.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ON.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            container.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.WHITE));
            OFF.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            ON.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }


}
```

and

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/ScreenActivity"
    android:clickable="true"
    tools:context=".ScreenActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="ON"
        android:id="@+id/ON"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="150dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="OFF"
        android:id="@+id/OFF"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="150dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I put the app in the emulator it crashes, so something is badly wrong.

I am not sure how View v should be passed to onClick and to changeScreen. I would hope that the View passed to onClick would also be passed to changeScreen, but I am unsure how exactly this would work.

In Android Studio, all the text seems to be fine (its not though).

Comment: What is the error, you are getting?

Comment: A crashing app. The error is so massive I cannot post it here. The problem seems to originate from the setting the visibility and the View

Comment: can please post your logcat here or tell what error you are getting

Comment: Atleast tell which type of exception you are getting/

Comment: @Darkie I have put some of the error of the logcat above. The error is so large I could not put all of it in

Comment: @NigamPatro see the above

Comment: For the first time its giving error or after some execution its giving error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Step1)*** First you add **color.xml** file into the **values** folder.(you can use **any name** for **color**)

***Step2***) Use like this into color.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <color name="White">#FFFFFF</color>
 <!-- White-->
    <color name="Black">#000000 </color>
 <!-- BLACK -->

</resources>
```

***Step3)*** Change a little changeScreen() method:

```
  public void changeScreen(View v) {
        ColorDrawable cd = (ColorDrawable) this.container.getBackground();
        TextView ON = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ON);
        TextView OFF = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.OFF);

        if (cd != null && cd.getColor() == getResources().getColor(R.color.Black)) {
            container.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.White));
            OFF.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            ON.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            container.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Black));
            OFF.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ON.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Im not sure why you have swapped round white and black in changeScreen()

Comment: Steps 1) and 2) I already had. Step 3) is exactly the same bar white and black are swapped round??

Comment: this code exactly running for me. i swapping black and white color because the default background is white.

Comment: sorry, are you saying that this code works for you in your IDE and complies and can be run in your emulator?

Answer (score 1):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        textview.setVisibility(textview.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);

    }
});
```

Comment: Please try to avoid just dumping a code as an answer and try to explain what it does and why. Your code might not be obvious for people who do not have the relevant coding experience.